# Show progress of seek bar

Tags: android, view, seekbar

I have an app where I use seek bars to mix colors and i would like above the seek bar there to be and number of how far the seek bar is. My seek bars go from 0 to 255 so the number would show possibly like 138/255 above the seek bar.

If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.
-Lfaudm

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SeekBar.onSeekBarChangeListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html#setOnSeekBarChangeListener%28android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener%29) to get changes of the value and then simply write that to a TextView you positioned above the SeekBar.